# Design Automation for AutoCAD - The process memory limit exceeded

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad, forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm working on a Drawing Automation task using Forge Design Automation for AutoCAD. Recently I've come across a memory limit issue. See the attached screenshot.

When I run the plugin on the local computer it works fine but throwing this issue on Forge.

The drawing file size I'm working on is around 500kb only.

[image: Forge DA AutoCAD - Memory limit exceeded issue]

Answer (score 1):

There are some limits for sure :)- it depends on the physical memory allocated on the machine instance. Design Automation runs on quite large machine (EC2 - m5.xlarge) and should not have problems running your plug-in and file. DA terminates the machine any time you are getting close to the limit. However, if you have a problem, I would recommend that you test your plug-in file on your local machine and in the Task Manager check how much memory is used.
If the problem persists we would need a reproducible sample to track the issue.